# How to make wx.Panel fill its parent wx.Panel?

Tags: wxpython

I have some troubles in understanding sizers.

My frame calls a wx.Panel of AreaPanel class. After a keyboard button is pressed with that panel active, I want to create a new wx.Panel of InventoryPanel class, that should fill the whole AreaPanel. It doesn't. I experimented in putting Layout() calls in different places, but clearly this is not the reason.

```
def Initialize():
        app = wx.App()

        frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Project')
        frame.SetSize(width = 1480, height = 600)

        arpanel = AreaPanel(frame)

        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()


class AreaPanel(wx.Panel):

    def OnKeyPress(self,e):
        key = e.GetKeyCode()
        print(str(key) + ' on panel: '+self.__class__.__name__)
        if key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            quit()
        elif key == wx.WXK_NUMPAD6:
            invpanel = InventoryPanel(self)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer.Add(invpanel,wx.GROW,wx.EXPAND)
            invpanel.SetSizer(sizer)
            self.Layout()
            self.Parent.Layout()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
        font = wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.DEFAULT)
        font.SetFaceName('Courier New')

        text = (('AreaPanel label.' * 10) + '\n') * 20

        self.mainText = wx.StaticText(parent, label=text, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.mainText.SetFont(font)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyPress)

        self.SetFocus()

    def DestroyChildPanel(self,child):
        child.Destroy()
        self.SetFocus()

class InventoryPanel(wx.Panel):

    def OnKeyPress(self, e):
        key = e.GetKeyCode()
        print(str(key) + ' on panel: ' + self.__class__.__name__)
        if key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            quit()
        elif key == 83:
            self.Parent.DestroyChildPanel(self)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
        font = wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.DEFAULT)
        font.SetFaceName('Courier New')

        text = (('InventoryPanel label. S to leave.' * 9) + '\n') * 15

        self.mainText = wx.StaticText(parent, label=text, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.mainText.SetFont(font)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyPress)

        self.SetFocus()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a sizer for InventoryPanel and add the InventoryPanel to this sizer. That's not correct.
Create a sizer for AreaPanel instead and add the Inventory Panel to it.
(And please follow usual conventions, e.g. **init** at the top of the class.)
P.S.: You write that you have difficulties understanding sizers. You may want to try wxGlade. Download it and work through it's tutorial. It includes a section about sizers.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dietmar. Going through wxGlade tutorial did in fact help me understand sizers a little better, the pics and descriptions you gave in wx Basics section of manual made some things very clear to me. As for the code - it did help! (after I corrected another mistake and switched from `wx.StaticText(parent, label=text, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)` to `wx.StaticText(self, label=text, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)`.